# Using RequireJS With automatically executed Javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm wondering how to use `RequireJS` with `JS` libraries like: *html5shiv* and *retina.js*, libraries like these don't need to be use the way we use jquery or something else. We just need to include it.

I'm currently using it an ugly way:

```
require(["html5shiv"], function () {
  //doing nothing here..
});
```

Any answers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS can have configuration method.
You can make shim by setting configuration.

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
     lib : 'libpath'
  },
  shim: {
     lib : {
        deps: 'related_lib',
        exports: 'html5shiv'
     }
  }

});
```

Then exported name can be used by other requirejs files.

Comment: yeah, I understand shim is for manage dependency and export a port, sorry for didn't made my question clearly. how to deal with libraries just need to include, however they don't need to be execute the old way: $('element').library();

Answer (score 0):

Following is the basic structure of using require.js with JS libraries in you application

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    html5shiv: '../lib/html5shiv', //or path to your html5shiv.js file; .js not required
    retina: '../lib/retina', 
  }
});

require([
  'html5shiv', 'retina'
], function(Html5Shiv, Retina){
  // Html5Shiv refer to html5shiv library
  // Retina refer to retina library
});
```

**Addition note:** (With libraries having dependencies)

```
// suppose lib1 is dependent on lib2

requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'lib1': '../path_to_your_lib1_js_file',
    'lib2': '../path_to_your_lib2_js_file',
  },
  shim: {
    'lib1': {
      deps: ['lib2']          
    }
  }  
});

require([
  'lib1', 'lib2'
], function(Lib1, Lib2){
  // Lib1 refer to html5shiv library
  // Lib2 refer to retina library
});
```

Hope you get the basic idea of using `require.js` with JS libraries

Comment: yeah, thanks for answering. However topic here is not the usage of requirjs but how to use it with libraries like html5shiv and retinajs, you don't need to write code but just link them in an elegant way.

Comment: Cheers!!! @Michael :) . Please be careful on those libraries which has dependencies. The library reference would be 'undefined' or 'behave' abnormally when dependencies doesn't load before actual library.

Comment: I edited my respond immediately after I published it, please have a double check.